# ruby on rails - test if array exist

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api

I'm getting an array from Facebook Graph Api using Koala on Ruby on Rails. It gives me user's news feed where elements look like that:

```
element = {"id"=>"561587517...", "from"=>{"name"=>"Name", "id"=>"5615..."}, "message"=>"Looking for an intern ...", }
```

What I would like to do is to see if element["message"] exists (which means that this element from news feed is a status update). I've tried

```
<% if defined?(t["message"]) %>
Status: <%= t["message"] %>
<% end %>
```

But it does not work and display "Status: " when the element is not a status update.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you probably want is:

```
<% if t.has_key?('message') %>
```

But in most cases, the following will do equally as well:

```
<% if t['message'] %>
```

Comment: Thanks ! If you know where can I find some docs around this kind of issues, it would be appreciated.